# Will dict __getitem__ create a copy of the corresponding object?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I saw following code from [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#example).

```
d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
```

I don't understand the meaning of doing so. It is said `retrieve a COPY of data at key`. Seems dict lookup (**getitem**, or indexing, which one is the proper term?) will make a cope of the object? Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing `shelve` module documentation.

`shelve.open` returns a dictionary-like object, not a dictionary. It does not load all key-value pair at once; so comments in the example make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily, dict lookup returns the value stored at the key, not a copy of the value. This is important for mutable objects. For instance:

```
A = dict()
A["a"] = ["Hello", "world"] # Stores a 2-element list in the dict, at key "a"
B = A["a"] # Gets the list that was just stored
B[0] = "Goodbye" # Changes the first element of the list
print(A["a"][0]) # Prints "Goodbye"
```

In contrast, `shelve` will return a *copy* of the value stored with the key, so changing the returned value will not change the shelved value.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing implementation (i.e. what `__getitem__` does for one specific type of object) for a specification (i.e. a prescription for what `__getitem__` should do all the time).

`__getitem__` just implements syntactic sugar around `x[i]` - it places no demands on *how* that is actually done. `x[i]` could just return the value associated with `i` in a dictionary. It could return a copy. It could cause way more side effects - i.e. it could cause files to be created/deleted, databases to be connected/disconnected, objects to be created/deleted, etc.

For `dict`, `__getitem__` is defined to return the original object. But you shouldn't assume those semantics will apply for all other objects that implement it - you will be disappointed. When in doubt, you are doing the right thing - check the docs.

Comment: I appreciate your answer with very clear and definitive phrasing. What I actually want to know is about the **implementation** of the built-in type **dict**.

Comment: OK, that's much clearer. If you do `mydict = {}; x = <something>; mydict['x'] = x`, then `x` and `mydict['x']` point to the same object; it returns the original reference, not a copy. Also, I should point that this is the 'normal' behaviour - _most_ of the time when objects implement `__getitem__`, it's like dict, and stores references. In the above, one reason `shelve` mentions COPY in 'bold' is because it is less common, and so worth mentioning.